# Returning a generic from a protocol-defined function in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, realm

I declared a protocol with a generic function, but it seems that the type inference isn't working properly after implementing it.

```
protocol SearchableRealmModel {
    static func search<Self: Object>(needle: String) -> Results<Self>?
}

class Thing: Object, SearchableRealmModel {
    class func search<Thing>(needle: String) -> Results<Thing>? {
        return realm()?.objects(Thing).filter("name == '\(needle)'")
    }
}

let things = Thing.search("hello") // works but inferred type is Results<Object>?
```

The problem here is that the inferred type of `things` is `Results<Object>?`. I realize these variations can be used,

```
let things: Results<Thing>? = Thing.search("hello")
let things = Thing.search("hello") as Results<Thing>?
```

but having to specify the type every time is quite repetitive.

In my tests, using other types than `Results<..>?` kept the type inference intact. And this could be caused by having to specify the parent class in `Self: Object` (which is required because of `Results`).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation of Swift's generics machinery. The compiler *can* generate a concrete signature for `static func search(needle: String) -> Results<Object>?` which satisfies the type constraint because `Object` subclasses will match this. You could probably file a bug towards [bugs.swift.org](https://bugs.swift.org) because I think the Swift core team would also consider this to be a bug, if not very unexpected behavior.

However, you can modify your code to use protocol extensions to do what you want:

```
protocol SearchableRealmModel {}

extension SearchableRealmModel where Self: Object {
    static func search(needle: String) -> Results<Self> {
        return try! Realm().objects(Self).filter("name == '\(needle)'")
    }
}

class Thing: Object, SearchableRealmModel {
    dynamic var name = ""
}

let result = Thing.search("thing1") // => inferred as Results<Thing>
print(result.first?.name)
```

If you want custom implementations of `search` for other Realm models, you can reimplement the function there, which the compiler will prioritize over the protocol extension version:

```
class OtherThing: Object, SearchableRealmModel {
    dynamic var id = ""

    static func search(needle: String) -> Results<OtherThing> {
        return try! Realm().objects(OtherThing).filter("id == '\(needle)'")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. The problem in my case is not optionals, though I did in fact forget to add `?` in this example. Please see my revised question.

Comment: I understand now based on your revised question. I've rewritten my answer accordingly. Please let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Thank you. That is indeed what I needed to make this work.